# Is there a Logout/Off procedure ?

Tags: support

I like to log out/off of a site when I leave it. I don't see a way to do that. Can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can log out, using the "Stack Exchange" pull down menu at the navigation bar. You will find your active community at the top, including a log out link.

[image]